# ReverseNotFound - Can't connect Detail View to List View

Tags: python, django, django-urls

When I try to go to the asset_list view, it gets hung up on the `get_absolute_url()` and throws the error

`Reverse for 'asset_detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en/marketing/$/<int:id>/']`

I am using a bunch of instances of this assets application around the site and each will serve out a few different assets based on a tag attribute. The Apphooks work great and everything is attached in the cms. I had everything working until I started experimenting with the detail views. I think I have two issues, one with the `get_absolute_url` and one in the `urls.py`

This is what I have

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import AssetListView, AssetDetailView

app_name = 'assets'
urlpatterns = [
    # List View
    url(r'^$', AssetListView, name="asset_list"),
    url(r'^$/<int:id>/', AssetDetailView, name='asset_detail')

]
```

**models.py**

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    description = PlaceholderField('asset_description')
    asset_category = models.ManyToManyField(Asset_Category, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    product_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    product_series = models.ManyToManyField(Series, blank=True)
    product_line = models.ManyToManyField(Line, blank=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, verbose_name='Video URL')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("assets:asset_detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

**views.py**

```
def AssetListView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    path = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(request.path))
    print(path)

    page_obj = Title.objects.filter(slug=path).first()
    print (page_obj)

    for obj in Tag.objects.all():
        print (obj.name)
        if obj.name == page_obj.title:
            queryset = Asset.objects.filter(tag=obj.id)
            context = {
                'object_list': queryset,
            }
            return render(request, 'asset_view.html', context)  

    queryset = Asset.objects.all()

    context = {
        'object_list': queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'asset_view.html', context)



def AssetDetailView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>AssetDetailView<h1>')
```

asset_view.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "content" %}
    <ul>
        {% for obj in object_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}}">{{ obj.name }}</a>
            </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>   

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is invalid, you can not put the `$` anchor in the middle here, since `$` means the *end* of the string. Furthermore since you use an `url(..)` this should be a regex, like:

```
url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', AssetDetailView, name='asset_detail')
```

Note that [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advices to write function names in lowercase with underscores between the words, so I would advice to rename your functions to `asset_detail_view` and `asset_list_view`.